# Cropped Full screen oval border with text inside with CSS text

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am struggling to imagine the best way to accomplish a layout I am trying to achieve which includes a static sized oval that is cropped for smaller screens and which contains text inside it that will respond based on the breakpoint.

The design is like this:
[image: Mobile version]

So far, I'm here:
[image: Not so good]

I'm trying to achieve this by creating the Oval outside my container div then putting on negative margin on the text to give it the appearance it is inside the oval. I feel like this isn't the right approach.

Currently set up (using Tailwind):

```
    <section id="reading">
      <div class="mt-12 border border-black rounded-[50%] overflow-hidden w-[686px] h-72"></div>
      <div class="flex flex-col mx-auto md:container">
      <div class="self-center justify-center px-8 text-center uppercase -my-80 py-28 text-ts3 font-title-preset">Text Headline Goes Here</div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

In my head, for the oval, I would just do margin:auto; overflow:hidden, and width:100% on the div, but that isn't working.

Any pointers on how you would approach this from a better practice perspective?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking separates the oval from the content within. A better way would be to keep them together by wrapping them both in a relatively positioned div and making the oval absolutely positioned to the top and center (then using a transform to center again which is a common pattern) and adding `overflow-hidden` to the relatively positioned element.

Not sure what your `text-ts3` class is meant to do since you did not share your config. But this example uses a few breakpoints with text size classes defined for each and some negative top margin on the text to make things look more vertically centered. Here is the example running on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/3zWymGzXPn

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>

<section id="reading" class="border border-transparent pt-12">
  <div class="overflow-hidden relative mx-auto md:container h-72">
    <div class="border border-black rounded-[50%] w-[686px] h-full absolute top-0 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2"></div>
    <div class="h-full flex items-center justify-center max-w-[686px] mx-auto">
      <div class="text-center uppercase -mt-4 sm:-mt-6 md:-mt-8 text-5xl sm:text-6xl md:text-7xl max-w-xs sm:max-w-sm">Text Headline Goes Here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the notes. I knew I had to have been overcomplicating it! That solution works perfectly. Re: text-ts3, sorry about that, forgot the config. This is just a custom size based on my design system (linking up with my figma file), so no worries there. I removed the container just to avoid the clipping if someone expands the window and all is ace.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the oval to 120% (or a fixed with per breakpoint) and the shrink to 0, so it does not shrink.

```
<section id="reading">
  <div class="flex h-screen w-full justify-center overflow-hidden bg-yellow-100">
    <div class="mt-12 flex h-56 w-[120%] shrink-0 items-center justify-center rounded-[50%] border border-slate-300">
      <div class="font-semibold">text goes here.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

See [example in tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rpYEUtoHUn).